# Why does my macbook pro displays random garbled blocks?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, display

Occasionally my macbook pro (15-inch, Early 2011 with mountain lion 10.8.2) displays random garbled blocks. This happens on external Apple displays and the laptop display. See photo.

[image]

Comment: Are you using gfxCardStatus by Cody Krieger? (If yes, update to the latest version.)

Comment: This problem continued to persist. I had to get the logic board replaced to fix this issue

Answer (score 1):

We had a lot of these problems in our store and in the most cases the graphic card was broken. You should run the [Apple Hardware Test / Apple Diagnostics](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH14291) and look at the results.

Comment: I've had the same thing on two machines. The graphics card was bad and Apple replaced it under warranty. In one case, twice in about 5 weeks.